# How to include “_beforeSuite” in test report?

Tags: codeception

We have a running api test suite on our CI environment.

Today I had a case where something broke in the code in the `_beforeSuite` function (in the response of some endpoint, I receive an empty JSON object).

Now, I am investigating any options, to include `_beforeSuite` in the test report, so in such cases, we could see what exactly went wrong on "CI test report" level.

**Expected behavior:**
When I launch my tests for example with
`codecept run tests/api --env stage1 --html my_report.html`
I want "my_report" to include steps from `_beforeSute` function